# linux can not excute binary file

Tags: linux, cpu, 64-bit

Recently I am doing a C++ project in Linux.I have executable file in Linux. I tried to run it and there showed an error: can not excute binary file. I saw similar questions here in SO and they said this situation happened when people tried to run a x86 program in an ARM CPU. But the problem is I am using an intel i5 3230m cpu and this should be x86 architecture. Quite strange.

There is another issue which I think might be related to this. When I install the Linux system in WMware player. Initially I tried to install the Centosx86_64 but failed(my laptop should be a 64bit system). I had to switch to Centosi386 to get it done.So it this also related to the version of WMware Player?

Can someone help me a little bit about this? Thank you!

Update: Ok ,I tried to use file and I get this is a 64bit file.( ELF 64-bit LSB executable,x86-64,version 1(GNU/Linux), dynamically linked(uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, not stripped ) And just now I tried lscpu(). What a surprise it shows architecture :i686 cpu op-mode:32bit. How could this happen? My processor is 32 bit architecture?!

Comment: You haven't said what your host system is, but if it's 32-bit then you can't run 64-bit programs either natively or in a VM. If you remember Windows 3 (a 16-bit operating system) there was an extension which allowed you to run 32-bit programs. Sadly, no-one has done the same thing to allow 64-bit programs to run on a 32-bit OS, though I can't see that the problem is any greater. Your only solution is to install a 64-bit host.

Comment: Did you compile the executable file from the source code on the same Linux installation where you are trying to run it?

Comment: My host system is 64 bit windows system and X64-based processor(I can see that form the property of system). This is a new laptop I bought last year with 6 GB RAM. I always thought this is 64 bit, how could it happen that now I am told this is 32 bit?

Comment: @AFH: Win32s had many limitations compared to a *real* 32-bit version of Windows. And it required, anyway, a physical 32-bit CPU. As 64-bit Linux is easily available, such a 64-bit environment for 32-bit Linux (probably with as many restrictions about what it can run as Win32s had) would just be lots of work to develop and maintain, while there is a much simpler alternative readily available.

Comment: @user3833612 It tells you 32-bit probably because you have a 32-bit version of Linux installed. Can you check your CPU type (cat /proc/cpuinfo)? So you can be sure you indeed have a 64-bit one.

Comment: @Ale - I agree on all your points, and I assumed (I hope, reasonably) that the CPU would be 64-bit, but if the host is a 32-bit OEM version of Windows then it will cost to upgrade to 64-bit, unless a dual-boot system with 64-bit Linux is a workable option.

Comment: @AFH you're right, I assumed the host was Linux too... ;-)